# Is there a way to create this feynman diagram with feynmf?

Tags: feynmf

I'm trying to make a diagram like this one using feynmf package

[image]

However I can't seem to make the vertical lines crossing the horizontal ones

I have this code

```
\begin{fmffile}{diagram-2}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(120,80) 
\fmfleft{i1} \fmfright{o1}
\fmf{plain,tension=4}{i1,v1} \fmf{plain}{v1,v2} \fmf{plain,tension=1,left}{v1,v2} \fmf{plain,tension=4}{v2,o1} 
\fmfdot{v1,v2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
```

however that produces only this

[image]

Is there a way to add the vertical lines to my diagram?